# How to perform eventhandling on ActiveX ListBoxes with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, event-handling, activex

Using the designer I created several ListBoxes on a worksheet and instead of writing a sub for each listbox for handling a click (etc.) I want to handle this in one sub.

I've read that this should be possible using a class and assigning existing listboxes to the eventhandler of that class.
But I can't get it working.

a) creating a class ~~~~ CListBoxEventHandler ~~~~ containing on the class module sheet

```
Public WithEvents CmdEvents As MSForms.ListBox

Private Sub CmdEvents_Click()
    MsgBox "Click Event"
End Sub
```

b) on the worksheet

```
Private lisHandlers() As CListBoxEventHandler

sub worksheet_activate()
    Dim numObjects As Long: numObjects = Me.OLEObjects.count
    ReDim lisHandlers(1 To numObjects) As CListBoxEventHandler
    dim i as integer: i = 0

    Dim ctrl As OLEObject
    For Each ctrl In Me.OLEObjects
        Dim progID As String: progID = ctrl.progID
        If (progID = "Forms.ListBox.1") Then
            i = i + 1
            Dim myListBox As MSForms.ListBox: Set myListBox = ctrl.Object
            myListBox.LinkedCell = ""
            Set lisHandlers(i).CmdEvents = myListBox
        End If
    Next ctrl
    Redim Preserve lisHandlers(1 to i) as CListBoxEventHandler

end sub

How should I do it and can I do the same with TextBoxes?

Also: cab I use ~~~~ myListBox.OnAction = "ListBox_Change" ~~~~ for each of the listboxes and distinguish between the listboxes by Application.Caller?
```

Comment: What is the issue exactly?  No MsgBox?

Comment: On the design side: are you really gaining anything?  You have 1 class per ListBox, and each class has an event handler.  So with 15 controls, you have 15 event handlers.  You've just changed where the event handlers live.

Comment: @BrianMStafford - I think the OP want all of their listboxes to call the same event handler - if they don't use this approach then there needs to be `Private Sub ListBox1_Click()`, `Private Sub ListBox2_Click()`, etc etc in the worksheet code module, and each time they add a listbox they need to edit the code.

Comment: @TimWilliams Yes, you're likely right but it was unclear from the post.  Although it could be he wanted 1 event for multiple controls similar to .Net.

Answer (score 0):

You have not created any instances `CListBoxEventHandler`

Creating an array of that type just gives you a set of references to `Nothing`, not an array of instantiated objects.

Untested:

```
Private colHandlers As Collection 'easier than an array...

Sub worksheet_activate()
    Dim ctrl As OLEObject, obj As CListBoxEventHandler
    Dim myListBox As MSForms.ListBox

    Set colHandlers = New Collection
    For Each ctrl In Me.OLEObjects
        If (ctrl.progID = "Forms.ListBox.1") Then
            Set myListBox = ctrl.Object
            myListBox.LinkedCell = ""
            Set obj = New CListBoxEventHandler
            Set obj.CmdEvents = myListBox
            colHandlers.Add obj
        End If
    Next ctrl
End Sub
```